# Address radio-button by ID for use in an event

Tags: jquery, events, radio-button, jquery-events

I have two radio buttons where I need an .click or .change event and I would like to address the radios using it's id.

```
<ul id="shipping_method">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="N1[0]" data-index="0" id="ID1" value="Val1" class="Cls1" checked="checked">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="N1[0]" data-index="0" id="ID2" value="Val2" class="CLs1">
    </li>
</ul>
```

First I tried the obvious (for me):

```
jQuery('#ID1').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked radio!');
});
```

Also tried:

```
jQuery("input[id='ID1']").click(function() {
    alert('You clicked radio!');
});
```

How do I address a specific radio using it's id in an event?

(I'm adding the the code in Wordpress that's why I use "jQuery" and not "$")

Comment: `jQuery('#ID1, #ID2').click(function() {`? Or `jQuery('input.CLs1').click(function() {`? Then use `this` or `$(this)` to reference the element.

Comment: I couldn't make it work :-( The radio's is located in a table, I don't expect it to make a difference but I'll  mention it just to be sure.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vo71vysq/. Although I see now on my second example that your classes aren't the same. One is `Cls1` and the other is `CLs1`

Comment: You cannot argue with a working fiddle :-P
If the click event is already set (somewhere) that could be a problem right? Or is it okay to make multible click events on the same element? Tried to track it down in developer console without success.
Maybe I should try to make an event on the parent element.

Comment: Multiple event handlers on the same element are totally ok.